# Checkbox without the square android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I would like to simply have the "tick" without the square. Also only as ImageView would be fine. Anyone knows the name of the resource in Android?

Comment: share screenshot of your desired output

Comment: I would like to have only the image, like this: http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/24/Check-icon.png

But without using an image defined by me, I would like to use the system-image (if possible).

Comment: it won't be *EVER possible*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set selector to drawable left to `Checkbox` in whatever shape you desire.

Do like this.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkImageSelector" />
```

`android:button="@null"` will remove the default image of square with tick and drawableLeft will place your image in place of that.

checkImageSelector.xml will be like this.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check" android:state_selected="true"/>    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked"/> 
</selector>
```

Comment: uhmmmm.. could you please give me an example of the resulting xml code?

Comment: ah ok, but I only would like to have the "system image" of the check, now one defined by me

Comment: i think that cant be done, you will be needing you own images as different devices have different icon for checkbox.

Comment: this was indeed the reason why I wanted to know if it was possible to use the system-defined image :) thanks though!

Comment: Hey assuming you are new here, You can accept the answers that properly fits for your questions. If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here:stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . But only if your question really has been answered.

Comment: yeah, actually I should accept the "It can't be done" comment lol

Answer (score 1):

You need two images for  **checked** and  **unchecked** state.

Create a `selector` with same resources :

checkbox_selector.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked_image" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked_image"/>

</selector>
```

Then set this selector as button :

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" />
```

Comment: so it can't be done using the images that Android uses? (I already knew how to do it with custom images.. I wanted to avoid that if possible :) ).

Comment: **No** you cannot do what you are saying

Answer (score -1):

Activity:

```
CheckBox.setButtonDrawable((int)getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
```

Fragment:

```
CheckBox.setButtonDrawable((int)getActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
```